# Unable to access changed default ssh port on AWS Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

I've changed default ssh port by performing the following steps;

1. Edit 22 to 2200 in **sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config**
2. restart ssh server by using **sudo service ssh restart**
3. Added a ufw rule **sudo ufw allow 2200/tcp**
4. Added a rule in EC2 security group in AWS management console to allow TCP 2200 from 0.0.0.0/0
5. SSH access to public IP using **port 2200** and using SSH private key

But it was it was unresponsive.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart sshd

> sudo service sshd restart

Not the ssh restart because ssh_config controls the behaviour of ssh not sshd

Comment: Do you using putty windows s/w or Ubuntu cli ? If cli then try pem instead of ppk

Comment: I use Putty to perform ssh access with ppk. It works whenever default port 22 is used but not port number other than 22.